# How to change the value of variables of another class using QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm writing a code that i used QWidget to create the widget that i wanted and later i set this widget as a central widget.

So far so good, but in the widget i had buttons, that if one of them was clicked it changed a string variable value.

After that i set this as a central widget, i created the same buttons in the MainWindow, but i can't change the values of the variables that i want anymore :(

```cpp
    {..... 
    linha_button=new QPushButton(this);
    linha_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(41,924),QSize(40,40)));
    linha_button->setIcon(QIcon(url_linha));
    linha_button->setIconSize(QSize(30,30));
    linha_button->setCheckable(true);
    QObject::connect(linha_button, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (lihaButton()));}

void MainWindow::lihaButton()
{
     Diagrama::modo="trafo";

}
```

The variable modo is declared in the widget named Diagrama.
This code don't execute, the error is:
invalid use of non=static data member 'modo'

How can I fix this??

Answer (score 1):

Declare a setter as a slot in your `Diagrama` class and connect your `MainWindow` to it:

```
class Diagrama: public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
...
public slots:
    void changeModo() { modo = "trafo"; }
};
```

In your `MainWindow` class:

```
QObject::connect(linha_button, SIGNAL (clicked()), yourDiagramaObject, SLOT(changeModo()));
```

Comment: it says that is not declared in this scope :(

Comment: `QObject::connect(linha_button, SIGNAL (clicked()), yourDiagramaObject, SLOT(changeModo()));` - better; `QObject::connect(linha_button, &QPushButton::clicked, yourDiagramaObject, &Diagrama::changeModo);` - will be checked at compile time, not run time and will be faster since it does not involve a bunch of nasty string comparisons (which the old-style macros cause). Use the new compile time checked, member function pointer based, syntax, please. The old `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macro crap needs to *die*.

Comment: @lukas Müller, you have to change `yourDiagramaObject` by the name of your own object.

Answer (score 0):

Or use lambda

```
connect(linha_button,&QPushButton::clicked,[this](){ modo = "trafo"; }) ;
```

Comment: His `modo` variable is in another class. It will not fix his problem, unfortunately.

Comment: if it is static maybe AnotherClass::modo in this case Diagrama::modo connect(linha_button,&QPushButton::clicked,[this](){ Diagrama::modo = "trafo"; }) ;